# Need help phrasing regular expression to find particular T-SQL pattern

Tags: sql-server, regular-expression

I know this is a Database Forum, but since the text I am trying to find is SQL-specific, I am hoping that somebody can point me in the right direction.  I need to search code to find places where the INSERT queries are written without explicitly specifying table column names.  For example, I need to find things like this:

```
INSERT tablename SELECT col1, col2 FROM anothertable

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (1), (2)
```

In case you wonder, when the column names are not explicitly specified after the table name, the SQL Server will implicitely assume that **all** of the columns are listed.  As a result, if you add a new column to the table, your code will break.

The regex pattern I envision would look for the following:

`INSERT` followed by any characters, followed by either `SELECT` or `VALUES` where there is no occurrence of closing parenthesis ")" before the `SELECT`/`VALUES`.

I was thinking about alternative way to phrase it, but I am not sure it's easier:

`INSERT` or `INSERT INT` followed by space/tab/cr/lf, followed by any number of characters, followed by space/tab/cr/lf, NOT followed by open parenthesis "("

I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Will you be using T-SQL for the actual search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "magic" regexp to do what you want is:

```
^[\s\t]*INSERT( INTO|)[\s\t\r\n]*[A-Za-z0-9_."\[\]]*[\s\t\r\n]*(SELECT|VALUES)\s
```

I tested some scenarios in "The Regex Coach" (a free software to test regexp). I made sure it also works for tables like [dbo].[tablename] or "tablename" etc.

Comment: It needs to allow other whitespace, such as tabs, in between the "Insert" and the "Into" words: `[\s\t]*INSERT[\s\t\r\n]*(INTO|)[\s\t\r\n]*[A-Za-z0-9_."\[\]]*[\s\t\r\n]*`

Answer (score 1):

If you not want to use LIKE statment to match INSERTS, you can enable regular expression using CLR - please see below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server